# ElasticSearch: analyze (check tokens) spesific filed of the document

Tags: elasticsearch

Can we analyze the specific field of the document? I found out only a command for analyzing text

GET index_name/_analyze
{
"text": "test your code"
}

Comment: you talk about that: 
GET _analyze
{
  "field": "{field}",
  "text": ["asd"]
} ?

Comment: I don't want to provide text myself, but instead, use filed value as a text